# Oozie global configurations

Tags: oozie

Based on [oozie doc](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a19_Global_Configurations) I understand that I can use the global element to avoid repeating, let's say, the job-tracker specification, for every action. Although, given the following simple workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="Test Hello World" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
  <global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
  </global>
  <start to="import"/>
  <action name="import">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      <exec>hw.sh</exec>
      <file>hw.sh#hw.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

when running `oozie validate` on it I get:

```
Error: Invalid app definition, org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 19; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'exec'. One of '{"uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1":job-tracker}' is expected.
```

So basically, it still expects a job-tracker element in the action.

If you have any idea on this behavior, your answers will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look at the **exact** XML schema definition for Shell action `xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1"` (with a stress on **0.1**)

Comment: By the way Oozie "validate" is notoriously un-reliable.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter regarding your above comment, Can you please provide an example of case where `oozie validate`  command behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: Actually I tried the thing once or twice, months ago, and then gave up because validation would fail but the job would run perfectly. Anyway the *"notoriously"* part is backed by this InfoWorld paper http://www.infoworld.com/article/3019754/application-development/16-things-you-should-know-about-hadoop-and-spark-right-now.html?page=2 (although the paper is quite severe in my opinion - Oozie is lame, yes, but what are the alternatives?)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the schema of `oozie shell action version 0.1`. You will notice that `job-tracker` and `name-node` tags require the minimum occurrence of 1 time. Same applies for the `exec` tag as well.

Source: [Shell XML-Schema](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_ShellActionExtension.html#Appendix_Shell_XML-Schema)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:shell="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
    <xs:element name="shell" type="shell:ACTION"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ACTION">
      <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="job-tracker" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="name-node" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="prepare" type="shell:PREPARE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="job-xml" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="configuration" type="shell:CONFIGURATION" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
             <xs:element name="exec" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="argument" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="env-var" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="file" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="archive" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="capture-output" type="shell:FLAG" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FLAG"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CONFIGURATION">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="property" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PREPARE">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="delete" type="shell:DELETE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="mkdir" type="shell:MKDIR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DELETE">
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MKDIR">
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now